# Simple iteration on 100 object to create id list is super slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm using pymongo to retrieve a cursor of 100 objects. The object only contain one key because I filter it and the mongodb query is fast enough.

The problem is that the result is a cursor of objects looking like this:
`{'id': 1588697856264716288}`

My goal is to have a list of 'id' but only interested in the value, so something like this:
`[1588697856264716288,1588697856264716289,...]`

In the code below, assume that `idd` is our cursor containing 100 object. It takes almost 20 second to eventually print `mylist`

```
mylist=[]
for idd in ids:
    mylist.append(idd["id"])
print(mylist)
```

Why is it so slow and how can I speed this up? I'm using Python3.10

I'm trying to create a list of id from a cursor faster. I tried using a simple for loop and maps but it always takes 15-20 seconds

Edit: I just realized what made it slow is the query (eventhough the cursor is returned really fast)

The query is something like this:

```
ids=mycol.find({"timestamp_ms": {"$gt":"1670979659"}}).limit(100)
```

In my database timestamp_ms is a string... I guess this is my problem. Should I convert it to a date to make it faster?

Comment: is the `iid` object making a call to your database when you request the `id` reference?

Comment: If `idd` is a cursor, is `idd["id"]` really a database query? [mcve], please.

Comment: It should absolutely not take 20 seconds to iterate over a list of 100 simple `dict` objects.

Comment: You need to show us what *ids* is

Comment: added the querry and identified the problem more in detail

Comment: I'm pretty sure the query isn't actually executed until you try to retrieve data from the cursor (which first happens when you enter the `for` loop).

Comment: If your table contains a very large number of rows **and** if the *timestamp_ms* column is not indexed then each query will probably have to perform a full table scan - which will be relatively slow. Also, we still can't see **exactly** what *ids* is

Comment: ids is the cursor, the result of the query

Comment: Idea: Print the time immediately before entering the loop then again immediately before the first append

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes do this:

```
from time import perf_counter

duration = None
mylist = []
start = perf_counter()
for idd in ids:
    if duration is None:
        duration = perf_counter() - start
        print(f'Duration={duration:.4f}s')
    mylist.append(idd['id'])
```

If the query is handled lazily - i.e., not until you first try to enumerate the cursor, then this will tell you how long the query takes

Answer (score -6):

If I remember correctly, list comprehension is faster than a for loop in Python (for some cases).

You could try the following solution:

```
ids = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]

mylist = [id['id'] for id in ids]
print(mylist)
```

The official docs for list comprehension: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: It's faster, but it's not going to be a factor of 20 faster (or whatever the OP is expecting). The only thing the list comprehension does is avoid multiple lookups of `mylist.append`. Something like `f = mylist.append; for idd in ids: f(idd["id"])` is going to be on par with the list comprehension.

Comment: The differences between list comprehensions and `for` loops wouldn't produce the kind of extremely slow execution reported (and if the OP tries using a list comprehension and it seems to fix things, that's because they changed something else and didn't realize it, not because the list comprehension actually helped).